# Apply a function to a dataframe and only return part of the dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, isbnlib

I have a df with an "isbn13" column. I also have a function called "isbnlib.meta". This function is from the library isbnlib. I would like to run the function on each row of the "isbn13" column. I'm using the apply function to do that.

```
df['publisher'] = df['isbn13'].apply(isbnlib.meta)
```

The issue is that the results for each isbn13 is a dictionary with various points such as Title, Author, Publisher, etc. I'm only looking for the "Publisher" result in the dictionary to be written out in my dataframe.

How do I only return the "Publisher" result in the dataframe from the dictionary results of the function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show the content in `isbn13`?

Comment: I've found a potential solution: df['publisher'].apply(pd.Series). This splits out all the metadata from the dictionary. Is that the best solution?

Comment: The content of isbn13 is a 13 digit string.

Comment: If your `publisher` column is a dictionary after the `apply`, you can perform a `map` operation to get only the publisher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your `isbnlib.meta()` returns a dictionary based on the value in your `isbn13` column. If so, you can use a lambda function in the same `apply`:

```
df['publisher'] = df['isbn13'].apply(lambda x: isbnlib.meta(x).get('Publisher', None))
```

In this case, if your `dict` doesn't have a `Publisher` key, it will return the default value `None`.

Comment: Hi Ricardo - Thanks for your response. I'm getting a key error "Publisher". I know that "Publisher" exists in the dictionary that's returned from the function because when I pass a single isbn13 as a string it returns with that dictionary option.

Comment: It seems that some of your books don't have the `Publisher` key. You can use the `.get` method of your `dict` object to return a default value if the `Publisher` key doesn't exist.

Comment: This is brilliant and much cleaner than what I was starting to do. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with the *isbnlib* library but assuming that *isbnlib.meta* takes in a string and returns a dictionary, you can do:

```
df['publisher'] = df['isbn13'].apply(lambda x: isbnlib.meta(x)['Publisher'])
```

Using a lambda function inside *.apply()* can be very useful for simple tasks like this one.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. This didn't seem to work, but I'm certain I didn't explain this well enough. The input for this function is isbn13, which is a code for book identification. When you send a single isbn13 through the function it returns the meta data. The one I want to isolate is "Publisher". If I do this:

isbn = '9780136858256'

book = isbnlib.meta(isbn)

publisher_isbnlib = book['Publisher']

publisher_isbnlib

I get back 'Pearson' which is what I want. So I'm looking to do this function for each row of isbn13 from the dataframe.